# Check Whether Time Falls between Two Time Values in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

My requirement is I want to check whether `Current Time` Falls between two `Specified Times`

**Scenario 1:**

```
TimeNow: 02:00:00(Tommorow)  
TimeSpan To Check 4am To 3am(next day)
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
TimeNow: 06:00:00  
TimeSpan To Check 4am To 3am(next day)
```

I wanted the above code in C#. 
I am not getting the logic to do so.

Comment: Is the "end" time always earlier than the "start" time? I'm assuming you would want the results to be "true" and "false" respectively, but you haven't actually said so. This question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean that there are two times, start and end and they may occur on either side of midnight, but the interval between them is always less than 24 hours, you will want to test (in pseudo code):-

```
 if (start < end) return start < desired AND desired < end
 else return desired < end OR start < desired
```

i.e. if the interval is wholly within one day, test to see if it's in that interval, otherwise if it wraps over the end of the day test to see if it's in either fragment.

Answer (score 0):

This method gives you if the current time is bigger or equal to startTime 
and if currentTime is less or  the same as the endTime

```
static bool Between(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

    if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime)
        return true;

    return false;
}

static bool Between(TimeSpan startTime, TimeSpan endTime)
{
    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(startTime.Ticks);
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(endTime.Ticks);

        return Between(dt1, dt2);
}
```

Comment: To make it more flexible, I'd put the date to check as a parameter. Maybe I want `DateTime.Now`, maybe I want `DateTime.UtcNow` or maybe I want any other `DateTime`. (Also, a little check if `startTime < endTime` and switch values if it isn't)

Comment: For the TimeSpan overload, instead of creating two Date objects and calling another function for comparision, you can get the CurrentTime in ticks (DateTime.Now.Ticks) and compare the numeric values.